# C# XNA: stopping and playing Cue (sound) objects

Tags: c#, audio, xna

I am trying to stop a Cue, then play it again. This code is in the Update() loop:

```
Cue torpedoSound = soundBank.GetCue("torpedo");
torpedoSound.Stop(AudioStopOptions.AsAuthored);
torpedoSound.Play(); // Invalid Operation Exception
```

However, I always get an `InvalidOperationException` at the above location. The documentation says that will occur if `Play()` is called on a `Cue` for which `isPlaying` is true. But if I call `Stop()` immediately before, how can this be?

This works fine:

```
soundBank.PlayCue("torpedo");
```

Placing a call to `Stop()` immediately after that allows the sound to play anyway, which surprises me:

```
soundBank.PlayCue("torpedo");
torpedoSound.Stop(AudioStopOptions.Immediate);
```

Shouldn't this make it never be audible to the user?

Additionally, when the sound is already playing, calling `Stop()` fails to stop it.

I'm new to C#/XNA.

Comment: I don't understand, you say you call Stop when it is already stopped, why? Then you say you call stop cause it's playing and you wanna stop it? Can u please explain

Comment: The sound is not already playing, but I am calling `Stop()` to be safe. Yet somehow, it still gives me an exception as if it was playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a Cue is stopped it can no longer be used. You have to get a new Cue instance from the audio engine.

Refer to this sample: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940205.aspx

Regarding the stopping, the Cue doesn't immediately stop when you call Stop. It can take a frame or two, or even more if there's an ending transition defined.